# Import and Display an Image in python in Google Colab

Tags: python, image, import, google-colaboratory

I am using **Google Colab** and python in this program and I want to import and display an image from my computer(it is in the end). I tried to import the image by uploading it to Google colab and then tried to display it by using imread() and imshow() functions. However, when I run the program, it asks me to select the file I need to upload, when I choose the file and click upload I get the following error for the imread line. Can you help please?

> "Object does not appear to be a 8-bit string path or a Python
>   file-like object"

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
from google.colab import files
from IPython.display import Image

uploaded = files.upload()
test = Image("C:/Users/cinar/Desktop/test/car/audi.jpg")

img=mpimg.imread(test)
imgplot = plt.imshow(test)
plt.show()
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfQYj.png